# Change Two digit year to 4 digit year with correct century (not allowed to modify two year cutoff date option)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, date-conversion

I tried to do a little research on this, but didn't have much luck.

I have a date (MMDDYY format) stored in a `varchar` field (DateValue) in a table that looks something similar to this:

### **TableA**

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
----------------------                                  
|| ID  |  DateValue ||
  -----  -----------    
|| 1   |  011212    ||
|| 2   |  011549    ||
|| 3   |  070860    ||
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am trying to add another column `ConvertDateValue` to the same table which would be a `date` field. The values in this column would be converted values from `DateValue` field in this format (YYYY-MM-DD). Here is what I have tried:

```
--declare table variable
declare @tableA table (ID int, DateValue varchar(50))

--insert sample values into table variable
insert into @tableA VALUES 
(1,'011212'),
(2,'011549'),
(3,'070860')

begin
select ID,
       DateValue,
       CAST(STUFF(STUFF(DateValue, 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-') as date) as ConvertDateValue 
 from @tableA 
end
```

**Output:**

---

```
|| ID  |  DateValue ||  ConvertedDateValue ||
  -----  -----------    ------------------
|| 1   |  011212    ||   2012-01-12        ||
|| 2   |  011549    ||   2049-01-15        ||
|| 3   |  070860    ||   1960-07-08        ||
```

**Expected Output:**

---

```
|| ID  |  DateValue ||  ConvertedDateValue ||
  -----  -----------    ------------------
|| 1   |  011212    ||   2012-01-12        ||
|| 2   |  011549    ||   2049-01-15        ||
|| 3   |  070860    ||   2060-07-08        ||  --Here is the difference
```

I need to ensure that the `ConvertedDateValue` is displaying correct century. The above value could also be `1960-07-08` for some data and not for others.

> FYI, I am aware of the two year cutoff date option and we have the default
>   value set for that i.e. year `2049`. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to change any of the advanced option settings for various reasons.

I am open to feedback and what alternatives are out there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: mistake #1: storing date/time values as strings. mistake #1b: storing it with an randomish ordering, instead of most->least significant. mistake #2 storing it with century digits, giving you a lovely Y2k problem, a mere 15 years after y2k was supposed to be dead/buried.

Comment: stuff a `'-20'` in there?

Comment: @MarcB  I agree! Thanks for pointing out the obvious! Unfortunately I am dealing with a third party vendor data that I am trying to transfer over.

Comment: I'd suggest taking the vendor out back and beating them to death with a rotten spaghetti noodle...

Comment: @MarcB For a second, I thought of that as well. But then I wondered is it worth losing your job for beating up your vendor to death with a rotten spaghetti noodle?

Comment: you boss would undoubtedly understand that having to find a new vendor is a minor issue compared to the world-wide benefits of eliminating a source of crap DB design...

Comment: @Nepali Rookie No court in the land would convict you as long as you had jury of your DBA peers. I'd definitely throw it into the category of justifiable noodling.

Comment: My question is how do you know which gets converted to 1900, and which to 2000? If you don't have some way of determining which is which I don't see how you can do this.

Comment: @jac Same question. You and me both. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty awesome, here is the substring to fix it:

```
select convert(date, cast(substring(DateValue,1,2) + '/' +  substring(DateValue,3,2) + '/20' + substring(DateValue,5,2) as datetime), 101 ) as converteddate
```

The convert isn't really necessary to populate the db, but it's the format you asked for.

Comment: Thanks Randall! This is a good answer, but my problem with this if I have value 070860...which may also mean 1960 (which is possible) for some data. I don't know how I could achieve that, but I will update this in my question.

Comment: Then it has to be some kind of case statement based on a different column, if I were lookign at the record in the DB how would I tell whether it was past or future?

Comment: That would be precisely my problem. :) Otherwise, this is really clear as mud.

Comment: brutal, it's more or less impossible without some outside hint when both future and past are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just manually parse the date and use a CASE statement to determine the century. If you want '070860' to sometimes be 2060-07-08, and other times to be 1960-07-08 then what logic besides the 2 digit year do you have to determine the century?

```
--declare table variable
declare @tableA table (ID int, DateValue varchar(50))
DECLARE @Month int
DECLARE @Day int
DECLARE @Year int


--insert sample values into table variable
insert into @tableA VALUES 
(1,'011212'),
(2,'011549'),
(3,'070860')

begin

select ID,
       DateValue,
       (CONVERT(varchar(4), CASE 
            WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(DateValue, 5, 2) AS int) > 88 THEN 1900 + CAST(SUBSTRING(DateValue, 5, 2) AS int)
            ELSE 2000 + CAST(SUBSTRING(DateValue, 5, 2) AS int)
    END)
    + '-' + SUBSTRING(DateValue, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(DateValue, 3, 2))
 as ConvertDateValue 
 from @tableA 
end
```

### Output

```
|| ID  |  DateValue ||  ConvertedDateValue ||
  -----  -----------    ------------------
|| 1   |  011212    ||   2012-01-12        ||
|| 2   |  011549    ||   2049-01-15        ||
|| 3   |  070860    ||   2060-07-08        ||
```

Comment: This is also a good answer...but again going to have similar issue to answer below. With this, your 19th century is limited to anything above year 1988. Thanks for the effort, @jac!

Comment: @NepaliRookie Thank you, I realized that, but left it anyway because it has the infrastructure to replace 88 with whatever you eventually find to make the decision for which century a year belongs to.